# Old Pavilion dv6 doesn't boot Fedora from USB drive

Tags: fedora, live-usb

I am posting here because I have no idea how to solve this and found no apparent solution here or elsewhere.

I have an old dv6 pavilion machine (2010ish) with Fedora 32 Workstation. I am trying to put Fedora33 LXDE on it for a lighter OS, but there is no way to make the pc boot the OS on the usb flashdrive. I have tried:

- Balena Etcher
- DD from linux terminal
- Fedora mediawriter
- Rufus with a variety of options, including flagging the 'fix for old bios' box, use the ISO write, use the DD write option.

I tried all USB ports, all drives I create boot on my other machines. And I did install Fedora 32 using the same USB back when I did it. I don't know what else to try and I am running out of tricks here. Thanks for any help you could give me!

Comment: What CPU is in your old laptop? Does it support the x86_64(x64) ISA? If not, you'll have to find a distro that still supports the old 32-bit x86 ISA. Did the laptop come with UEFI/EFI or just a legacy BIOS? Does Fedora 33 LXDE support legacy (non-efi) boot?

Comment: It's an interesting question, but you can install LXDE, remove package groups you don't need and upgrade, or first upgrade - I don't think it matters much.

Comment: @svin83 this is the output from my lscpu:
`lscpu
Architecture: x86_64
CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order: Little Endian
Address sizes: 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s): 2
On-line CPU(s) list: 0,1
Thread(s) per core: 1
Core(s) per socket: 2
Socket(s): 1
NUMA node(s): 1
Vendor ID: GenuineIntel
CPU family: 6
Model: 23
Model name: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P8600  @ 2.40GH`
laptop came with just legacy bios. I can't find any actual info on Fedora 33 not supporting legacy bios...

Answer (score 0):

Solved as follows:

press ESC and then F10 to get into BIOS, navigate to BOOT order setting, even if they are correct confirm them and press F10 to save and exit. Then it will BOOT from USB. Believe this is specific for this laptop model.